# Coffeescript unmatched outdent error

Tags: coffeescript

I'm getting the error `SyntaxError: Unmatched OUTDENT on line 9` when I try to compile the following coffeescript code. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. the indentation seems to be right, and I have everything where I want it.

```
row_possibilities = (grid) ->
  for rows in [0..8] by 1
    for columns in [0..8] by 1
      if(Array.isArray(grid[rows][columns])
        for possible_val in grid[rows][columns] by 1
          grid = unique_row_possibility(grid, rows, columns, possible_val)
          if(Array.isArray(grid[rows][columns]) == false)
            break
  return grid
```

What the code is supposed to do is run the three for loops and breaks the innermost for loop if a certain condition happens.

After all the for loops run. I want to return the variable grid. I've double checked the spacing, and I tried it out on repl.it, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Missing closing paren on `if(Array.isArray(grid[rows][columns])` on line 4?

Comment: That was it. That type of stuff always seems easier in hindsight. Also, if you want to make your comment an answer, I can acccept it.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes after you have been staring at code for too long.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

A bit tough to see but it appears that you are missing a closing parenthesis on line 4:

```
if(Array.isArray(grid[rows][columns])
```

In general, for this particular error, the problem will almost always lie with indention or unbalanced parenthesis or brackets/braces.

Comment: Aaah, how did I forgot that!?

Comment: @JesseVogt - thank you - is there a program which can quickly identify unmatched parentheses? Same error but I can't seem to spot it! chrs

Comment: @bkspurgeon some code editors will highlight matching parenthesis

Comment: This kind of error message is better than no message only if the line number is omitted